# How to add single quote in object javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to add single quote in object javascript ??
i want save the data in Api i need the format like this  '["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657"]' but i got the
data like this ["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657","5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e658"].

how to add single quote '["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657"]' like this in javascript ?? please let me know

Comment: I would escape the single quotes like this: `console.log('\'["5f...."]\'')`, but IMHO I try to understand why you want to save it like this

Answer (score 1):

Use backtick.

```js
let a = `'["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657"]'`;
let checkArray = [];

checkArray.push(a);
checkArray.push(a);
console.log(checkArray);
```

Comment: i have save multiple ids so i have save data in variable checkArray.
 selectedSurveysId:  checkArray
so how can to that ?

Comment: Array you can push the same variable strings using backtick.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach

```js
let userIds = ["alice", "bob", "carla"]
let array = JSON.stringify(userIds)
console.log(`'${array}'`)
```

Comment: yes it working when console it '["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657"]' but when i pass value in api then double quote added 
 selectedSurveysId: "'["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657"]'"
yearlyBasePrice: "2323"

Comment: yes, exactly, because is a string. Strings will always begin and end with a double quote

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = ["5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e657","5f22bbaab5c57c0017f1e658"]; // YOUR_DATA

const withSingleQuote = arr.map((id) => `'["${id}"]'`); // returns Array

console.log(withSingleQuote);
```